# How do I search for the comma character within data stored in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have some data that I needs to be searched for the comma character.

example entry I need to locate in the field Citation in the Citations table:
**This is sometimes true, Textual Reference**

In the end, I'm looking to extract **Textual Reference**

Selecting the column with the data:

```
select Citation from Citations;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works to select the data, but doesn't isolate what I want:

```
SELECT        Citation
FROM            Citations
WHERE        (Citation LIKE '%\,%' ESCAPE '\')
ORDER BY Citation
```

Ah, this works:

```
    SELECT Citation,
           SUBSTRING(Citation,
              CHARINDEX(',', Citation) + 1,
              LEN(Citation) - CHARINDEX(',', Citation)) AS Truncated
    FROM            Citations
    WHERE        (Citation LIKE '%\,%' ESCAPE '\')
    ORDER BY Truncated
```

Thanks ck!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT        Citation
          , SUBSTRING(Citation, CHARINDEX(',', Citation) + 1, 
                      LEN(Citation) - CHARINDEX(',', Citation))
FROM            Citations 
WHERE        (Citation LIKE '%\,%' ESCAPE '\') 
ORDER BY Citation
```